# How to use path and basepath in java web page?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

In a jsp page,we usually see the code.

`< %
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>`

I get the static resource using this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=path%>/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

but I find that using the other way is also ok.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=basePath%>/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

What's the difference?When should I only using `basePath`?Or have  they the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basePath` is the absolute path of you web application for example

```
http://example.net:8080/mycontext/
```

whereas `path` is only the context path i.e.

```
/mycontext
```

Using the `basepath` to fetch (static) resources works in a simple network topology / setup. In a scenario where your application is behind a load balancer using the `basePath` destroys the idea of the load balancing because the request goes to the same host and port as the JSP.

Because your web application may be behind a load balancer, a firewall, or a web server it is not recommended to use the `basePath` approach just because you have no idea which URL the user sees in a more complexer network setup.

Comment: So is it better to use path than bathpath?

Comment: @flower As long as you don't have any good reason to use the base path it's recommended to use the context path (i.e. your `path` variable)